# Copy Image from one Sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched through out Google and on here for a proper answer and I can't seem to find one...

I have an image on "Sheet2" that I want to copy over to "Sheet1", the image's name is static and doesn't change. I've got the below code to delete the already existing image on "Sheet1" and now I need it to be replaced with the image from "Sheet2"

```
Sub CheckImageName()

    For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Not Intersect(shape.TopLeftCell, Range("L77:AM97")) Is Nothing Then
            shape.Delete
        End If
    Next shape

End Sub
```

Every method I saw was using `.Select` and pasting into the area, however I'm really trying to avoid using the `.Select` and `.Paste` methods as I've read all over SO and other sources that it's best to avoid using `.Select`.

Comment: This is one case where you need to use copy/paste

Comment: While it is best to avoid using `.Select`, at certain times it's the only way to go, so you have to! `Select` is there for a reason, to `Select` things when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @ScottHoltzman, can you put this as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Why `.Select`? How about `Sheet2.Shapes("MyShape").Copy: Sheet1.Paste`?

Comment: @Excelosaurus I need an object to reference with that method

Comment: Won't it have the same name once on Sheet1? `Set myShape = Sheet1.Shapes("MyShape")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a response for Word that could apply for your question.

> [Copy shape in Word 2010 without .Select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816041/copy-shape-in-word-2010-without-select)

```
Sub createShape()
    Set myshape = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 100, 100, 100, 100)
    Set anothershape = myshape.Duplicate
End Sub
```